# Make org-mode markup symbols invisible?

Tags: org-mode, font-lock, formatting

In Emacs, one can use asterisks * to achieve bold font, for example, ***bold***. My question is can I make the asterisks invisible? i.e. **bold** instead of ***bold***.
Same question for strike through, italics, etc.

I know this should be achievable. As an example, one can set the org-indent asterisks the same color of the background, so it becomes invisible:

```
* Headline one
** Headline two
```

vs.

```
* Headline one
 * Headline two
```

You can still move the caret over to see the asterisks there, which is nice.

Back to my question, I don't know if or how to do the same thing for the markups in text formatting.

Comment: The question is not clear. If this is about a particular mode (e.g. Org mode? some markup mode?) then please elaborate. You refer to "*the markups*", without any explanation of what you mean. In Emacs in general there is *no markup* and you *cannot* use`*bold*` to achieve **`*bold*`**.

Comment: The ole asterisk vs asteroid confusion, Luke.

Comment: @Alex I am assuming that you were referring to org-mode in this question and editted it accordingly. Without that as Drew mentioned, this question is unclear. Feel free to revert my edits and clarify the question as suitable.

Comment: Hi folks, thanks for replying. I've edited my post, hopefully it's clearer. My question is in the first paragraph. All the rest is just an example of what inspired the question. Thanks all!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If your question is specifically about org-mode and its emphasis markup: try customizing `org-hide-emphasis-markers`. You can set that to `t` to hide the markers around words in bold, italics, etc.

Comment: Actually this answers my question. Just curious, how does it work behind the scene? For example, if I just want to set the font color of the markers, where do I edit?

Comment: @Alex You can customize `org-emphasis-alist` to specify the faces you want to use for the various kinds of markup.

Comment: `org-hide-emphasis-markers`  [no match]

Comment: Sorry: `M-x customize-variable` and `org-hide-emphasis-markers`